# java byte array to String

Tags: java, string, binary, arrays

I am trying to make a *Java binary translator*, and I have gotten to the part of translating the binary back to a `String`. I have made it to a `byte` array. I want to convert it to a string.

For example, I want a new `byte` array of `{01000001, 01100001, 01000010, 01100010}` to return `"AaBb"`.

How can I do this?

Comment: How about using `String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)` Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the specified charset.

Comment: (And, actually, if you already have the byte array, and not the binary bits in a character string or some such, you're done.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not having studied the constructors of String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want to do is convert a binary (decimal) number to its ASCII representation. If so, try something like this:

```
public class ByteArrayToAsciiChar {

  public String byteToCharacter(byte b) {
    return Character.valueOf((char)b).toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] byteArray = {
        0b00100101,
        0b01000001,
        0b01100001,
        0b01000010,
        0b01100010,
        0b01010101
    };

    ByteArrayToAsciiChar testClass = new ByteArrayToAsciiChar();

    for (byte b : byteArray) {
      System.out.println("Byte: " + b + " ==> " + testClass.byteToCharacter(b));
    }

  }

}
```

Which gives this output:

```
Byte: 37 ==> %
Byte: 65 ==> A
Byte: 97 ==> a
Byte: 66 ==> B
Byte: 98 ==> b
Byte: 85 ==> U
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Erm ... it is as simple as this:

```
    byte[] bytes = {0b01000001, 0b01100001, 0b01000010, 0b01100010};
    String str = new String(bytes, "ASCII");
```

Of course, that assumes that the bytes represent ASCII encoded characters.  If not then use the name of the *actual* character encoding.

If you are going to do this a lot, then it is worth looking up the `Charset` object for the character set and using the `String(byte[], Charset)` overload.

Comment: Indeed, the latter is even better as you can be sure at compile time that the desired charset really exists. Yet it doesn't work only from Java7 on.

Comment: @Ingo - It works in Java 6 too - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset).  And probably earlier.

Comment: Oha! Silly me. But I remember in Java6 there were some constructors that only accept a charset name (and throw exceptions when the name is not correct) and not a charset. Maybe InputStreamReader or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a byte array (exemplarily constructed below), you can easily pass the byte array to a new String (as [Ingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86604/ingo) suggested) and viola - you're done.

```
byte b[] = new byte[4];
b[0] = Byte.parseByte("01000001", 2);
b[1] = Byte.parseByte("01100001", 2);
b[2] = Byte.parseByte("01000010", 2);
b[3] = Byte.parseByte("01100010", 2);

String output = new String(b);
```

If you only have an array of binarys in form of strings, you could use this:

```
public String convertBinaryArrayToString(String binary[]) {
    String ret = null;
    for (String i : binary) {
        ret += (char) Byte.parseByte(i, 2);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Hope this helps.